# DirectX 11 Buffer Location

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-11

In DirectX when you want to create a VertexBuffer, IndexBuffer or ConstantBuffer you rely on [ID3D11Buffer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**What I want to know is where is this buffer created?**

Is it in system memory or video memory.

And what exactly happens when you use [ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set a vertex buffer and the corresponding methods for IndexBuffer and ConstantBuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> In Direct3D 10/11, an application no longer specifies what type of memory (the pool) to create a resource in. Instead, you specify the intended usage of the resource, and let the runtime (in concert with the driver and a memory manager) choose the type of memory that will achieve the best performance.

There's no guarantee about where resources like buffers are stored.
The only way you can "control" where the resources are created is by choosing the correct `D3D11_USAGE` for them.
`D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` and `D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE` resource will probably end up in VRAM,  `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` and `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING` in some memory region that is both accessible to the CPU and GPU.

Just make sure you choose the fastest usage for your resources according to their neeeds
`D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE` > `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT` > `D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC` > `D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`